# Make matplotlib colormap from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm making a surface plot on matplotlib. My axes are x, y, and depth. I have a two dimensional array which has RGB values, and the index corresponds to the (x,y) coordinate. How can I make the colormap from this 2D array? Thanks.

Code that makes numpy array:

```
import Image
import numpy as np
def makeImageArray(filename):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    a = np.array(img).astype("float32")
    return a
```

Image is in greyscale.

Comment: when you say your RGB array is 2d, are you including the dimension along RGB?  That is, is 2d array of pixels with 1d for color, or a 1d array of pixels with 1d for color?

Comment: I just took a photo and converted the image to a 2-dimensional numpy array. I'm not sure what your question was asking, but sorry if my question was badly written.

Comment: Just a technicality; if you have an ordinary color image, it would actually be 3d, since its `shape` would be something like `(600,800,3)` for three colors.  Grayscale would be `(600,800)`.  It sounds like your RGB array is technically 3d, since it represents a 2d image in color..

Comment: This is the sample of my code that converted it to an array:

import Image
import numpy as np
def convertToArray(filename):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    a = np.array(img).astype("float32")

    return a

It just came out as a 2D array. The max is 255 and the min is 0 so it is RGB. This was for an unprocessed image

Comment: Sorry for the bad code formatting, but I accidentally posted it before finishing it because I'm new to the site, so I wasn't aware that new lines were done with shift+enter, and then I ran out of time to edit it. But yeah, it was still in black and white and upside-down, if this helps to show how unprocessed it was.

Comment: You can edit the question itself, if you want to add information to it.  Yes, if it's a truly 2D array, it will be grayscale.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather for every point (x,y) you have two pieces of information, the height and the color. You want to have a surface plot using the height, and colored according to the color at each location.

While you can easily specify [custom color maps](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps) I don't think this will help you.
What you are thinking of is not that the same as a colormap which maps the height at (x,y) to a color.

The result is most evident in the Surface plots example [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)

I believe what you want is beyond the scope of matplotlib and can only be done with some kind of hack which I doubt you will wish to use.

Still here is my suggestion:

```
import pylab as py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

colorise = [((5.0 + X[i][i])/10.0, 0.5, 0.0) for i in xrange((len(X)))] 

ax = py.subplot(111, projection='3d')
for i in xrange(len(X)):
    ax.plot(X[i], Y[i], Z[i], "o", color=colorise[i])

py.show()
```

This produces the following:
[image: Example]

Importantly this displayed a 3D surface with the colouring not dependant on the height (it is a gradient in on direction). The most obvious issue is that coloring individual points looses matplotlibs surfaces making it painfully clear why the 3d plotting is called a *projection*!

Sorry this isn't very helpful, hopefully better software exists or I am unaware of matplotlibs full features.

Comment: To do this, you don't need the explicit loop.  there is the 3d `scatter` on the page you linked to which accepts an array of the same shape as the color keyword.